# Bisecting k-means convergence to global minima

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

I read that Bisecting k-means algorithm helps to converge to global minima. I am not sure if this is correct as I couldn't find a source or research paper that approves this claim. Can someone tell if this claim is correct?

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reasons (study the algorithm) it cannot guarantee to converge to the global optimum.

So wherever you read that, it probably was a different statement.

Finding the global optimum would.be NP hard - you don't want that.